# Mac dev folder missing, SSH not working

Tags: mac, unix, ssh

A few days ago, SSH stopped working.

1. Can someone help me get SSH to work (it used to)
2. Help me understand the UNIX dev folder
3. Are there any PUTTY like Mac clients.

When I try logging in with SSH I get the following message:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
stdin: is not a tty
fatal: unrecognized command ''
Connection to 74.52.61.194 closed.
```

Web searches have shown me that there might be something wrong with /dev/std/ folder.
But I have revealed hidden folders and cannot find the /dev/ folder (There is an alias to dev, but Mac claims it is a broken link) ditto when I search for it with other tools such as Houdini. I could cd into it though, so am confused what is up with this folder.

Are there any tools that can save my SSH preferences so that I don't have to, each time, type out the username@adrees, password, path all of which are long and complex?

Not looking for a Filezilla type client, there are many of those.  Looking for a command line like putty, that lets me use bash on the remote client.

Am on Macbook Pro, latest version of Tiger.

EDIT:
Have tried to SSH with -v, here is the output, if it can help a knowledgeable super user?

```
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 74.52.61.194 [74.52.61.194] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '74.52.61.194' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/me/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: perl -e 'exec qw(git-shell -c), $ENV{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}'
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Remote: Forced command: perl -e 'exec qw(git-shell -c), $ENV{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}'
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
stdin: is not a tty
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
fatal: unrecognized command ''
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 74.52.61.194 closed.
Transferred: sent 2448, received 2856 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6027.2, received 7031.8
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Comment: You cannot `cd /dev/` in Terminal on Mac OS X? Really?

Comment: No, I could.  Hadn't tried. Now am truly confused.  Tried now with Houdini, got an Applescript Error. Tried with the open files dialog of TextWrangler, it did not succeed either.  So, totally confused, will update question to be clearer.

Comment: As a matter of interest, have you tried connecting to more than one ssh host?

Comment: If you know a bit of Unix, you also see no `/bin`, `/etc`, etc.. These are simply hidden. Press `Cmd-Shift-.` in open file dialogs to show hidden files and folders and mess up your system if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the **Terminal.app** to do SSH, and for hosts that you regularly connect to, you create aliases and set up encryption keys so you can do faster logins.

To create an alias:

```
alias gohost='ssh myname@myhost.net'
```

Of course, call the alias something useful to you, instead of `gohost`.

To create a ssh key, you do:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then follow the prompts, accept defaults unless you know what you're doing. Leave the pass-phrase blank if you want password-less login, if you want to retain password login, just skip the ssh-keygen and use `gohost` to connect to your host.

The good thing about ssh keys, is that you can do `scp` (secure copy) and `rsync` over ssh, without having to re-enter your password all the time, of course you want to make sure your account on the Mac is secure, so that only you can use these keys, (they're linked to your account, and stored in the `~/.ssh` folder.)

If you create a ssh-key you need to copy the public key to your home on server, so let's copy the public key to the clipboard.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
```

(`pbcopy` takes standard input and places it in the mac clipboard, `pbpaste` does the opposite, and sends the contents of the clipboard to standard output, but only text.)

Then connect to the ssh host, and then do:

```
cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Paste the key from the clipboard, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, exit from the host, and then try connecting again, if all has gone well, you'll just find yourself at the host prompt again, without needing a password.

### Why isn't your ssh working?

Looking at your debug output there's a couple of things that aren't clear. First of all, it looks like your `ssh` installation is ok.

The error message also suggests that `/dev/pty` doesn't exist, check it does (not in Finder) ...

But this looks like it's a server error, have you tried ssh to another server?

### Dev folder

If you can't do `sudo ls /dev` then something is badly wrong with your system.

To explain what `/dev` is, Unix (which OS X is built on top of) uses `/dev` to access devices, standard input, standard output, hard disks, cd/dvd drives, etc.

This allows Unix to access devices as part of the file system, to 
communicate with them.

In general use, you should leave the `/dev` folder alone, some GUI tools (Backup software for example, or in your case Houdini) will occasionally report some error or another about it, because it isn't a folder they will understand. (Ideally they should ignore it.)

Comment: Thanks. SSH from a Windows computer using Putty works fine, so I don't think its the server.  I did sudo ls /dev, and it worked, thanks.  And there is no dev/pty folder. Am I supposed to create it, and if so how? (sorry, noob here. But am learning quick).  Also, where does it put the alias created by the above command? Cannot find it.

Comment: Well, IF the `/dev/pty` device/folder is the problem, it would need to be mounted, so you could do `mkdir /dev/pty`, add it to `fstab` and then do `mount -a` (mounts everything in fstab). However, I think it's worth figuring out why this broke in the first place - I'd like to try this (I'm away from Mac's today, but can look in a few hours.)

Comment: Have used sudo mkdir to make the folder, but it hasn't changed the errors at all. I guess something should go inside said folder?  Thanks very much. EDIT: Oops didn't see your comment.  OK, how do I go about figuring out whats wrong?

Comment: You can try looking up fstab use on the Mac in the meantime.

Comment: `alias` commands should be in your shell startup, if you use bash, `~/.bash_profile` is the place to put them.  Just edit/create it and put your aliases at the end. More info on alias here - http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html

Comment: I really think the `/dev/pty` is referring to the server, it should be the device that is providing the tty connection (your console on the server) - Regardless of whether this server works with PuTTY on Windows, can you `ssh` on the Mac, to another ssh host?

Comment: See here for a description of `pty` http://linux.die.net/man/7/pty

Comment: (In other words, don't create the `/dev/pty` folder locally, you should remove it.)

Comment: Just tried.  Yes, I can SSH to another server (one run by nearlyfreespeech.net) And am reading up on fstab. And thank you very much for the time and effort.

Comment: can you ssh on the Mac, to another ssh host?  (try a few, unrelated hosts) - if you get the same error, then we can confirm that it's the ssh setup on your mac.

Comment: So, you won't need `fstab`, in this instance, because it's the server that's not providing a `pty` device for your ssh session. If an ISP maintains the server, or another org. with a support desk, you should raise a ticket with them.

Comment: OK, Ive opened a ticket with them. Am marking this as correct, but will update it one way or another if I get useful response from Site5, the host. [Their agent has thus far agreed to open the ticket, but claims it is a computer issue, since he can do from his Windows machine].

Comment: Yes, unfortunate the old "it works from my machine" response, as long as you give them the full trace, and can demonstrate that you are able to connect to other ssh hosts, they should be able to figure out why their ssh host isn't providing a pty/tty for you.

Comment: The most telling line of the trace out is this : `debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.` (which is a message from the Remote host saying... well, you can see ;) ) ... this line `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0` is the local ssh client saying it couldn't get a PTY, and it needs one.

Comment: Update: Site5 claims the issue is that I am sending my github rsa. Delete and all will be fine. Meanwhile, I get the same pty error when I try to ssh to github!!  Will play with this a bit, moving keys. But need a solution that will allow me to use github from the command line, as well as ssh.

Comment: You can't ssh to github, it will only allow you to use the SSH protocol for git operations, not for ssh/tty login. That's why it's giving you the pty error there.  I'm not sure why your github.rsa is causing a problem. I use github often and have no issues with other ssh hosts.

Comment: Their response: 
Sure, you just need to specify specific key to use for SSH. You can use same key for GIT and regular SSH.

cat <<EOF> /Users/me/.ssh/config
Host 74.52.61.194
IdentityFile /User/me/.ssh/site5
EOF

create a new key like you did for git, and place public key in authorized_keys on your account with us. after that, simply ssh the way you used to and it'll use key from /User/me/.ssh/site5 for it.

id_dsa/rsa is the default key it will offer to remote servers, that's why it works here, doesn't work somewhere else since you didn't authorize it.

Comment: That worked. Once I created the config file, and added a new ssh keypair to the remote address, it connected and all was fine.
Would it be possible to edit the best parts of this into your answer, so that future readers can get the working conclusion. And so that I can understand why this worked, while acknowledging that it *does* work. Also, let me point out that when I ssh to github themselves - and the ssh key for them is good - I also get a pty error. It connects, just throws an err. Acc to them, that is the correct behaviour. An explanation from knowledgeable slomojo would be appreciated.

Comment: Oops. Sorry about reposting about github. I meant to write that while github does not accept SSH, they recommend doing `ssh git@github.com` in order to check that the authentication is setup correctly. Correct behavior is to acknowledge the authentication as being correct, but to throw a pty err, as well as a statement that ssh is not supported.  I just wanted to demonstrate that pty errs should not be stopping the connection, and that they do get thrown on servers other than site5's. Don't really understand actually. http://help.github.com/mac-key-setup/

Comment: I can't really edit in the solution, because it is specific to your account with Site5, and therefore not generic, as it happens there's nothing in the error log you've posted to suggest a public key error. And certainly any SSH server will be accessible via PAM (password), so it's a bit odd.

Comment: Just to make it clear why I can't edit in the solution, because of this logical disconnect between the error log and the declared solution from Site5 .. I simply don't understand either! :)

Answer (score 2):

The following is what worked for me.
It is being written to help others who run into the same issue, but is not the "correct" answer, as I am pretty sure it should not have worked.
Read the thread on slomojo's answer to get the whole rundown.

1. **Symptom**:
   SSH on the Mac stopped working to my Site5 hosted server.
   I was able to SSH to other servers without an issue.
   **Issue**:
   SSH will automatically send any key(s) in the .ssh/id_rsa or .ssh/id_dsa files.
   When setting up GitHub accounts it is common to create these files.
   Site5 was getting and borking on the unrecognized GitHub keys.
   **Solution**:
   I moved the GitHub private key from .ssh/id_rsa to another file (eg .ssh/GitHub) and added a config file to direct SSH to that key.
   Once the GitHub key was not being pushed to the site5, everything worked.
   From a security standpoint this sounds like a big deal, as otherwise it would seem easy to have my keys stolen.  (I don't understand SSH, so may be missing something obvious.)
2. The dev folder had nothing to do with my issue, which was server side.
   Nonetheless, the dev folder is best explained here:
   http://www.mackb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/macintosh/3883/That-mysterious-dev-folder
3. To create Aliases, Slomojo writes:

> alias commands should be in your shell
>   startup, if you use bash,
>   ~/.bash_profile is the place to put
>   them. Just edit/create it and put your
>   aliases at the end. More info on alias
>   here - ss64.com/bash/alias.html

Good luck all!